# LUIS datetime entity not working on Spanish culture

Tags: datetime, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I have a LUIS application using an es-es culture with some intents and I am using the prebuilt datetime entity but when adding new utterances it cannot map it to Spanish words like:

hoy (today), ayer (yesterday) or este mes (this month).

Is this something that is still in development for languages that are not en-us? Or it should be working?

Thanks!

Manuel

Comment: Hi Manu, are you still running into this issue with es-es?

Comment: Thanks Steven for your reply. Yeah, I'm still running into this issue. I've just tested it again right now and it´s only able to map 'esta semana'(this week) when using the app with es-es culture. Whereas an app with the en-us is capable to map the following into the prebuilt datetime: last week(semana pasada), last month (mes pasado), this month(este mes), last year(año pasado), this year(este año), yesterday(ayer), today(hoy) and tomorrow(mañana). Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The LUIS team is working hard on improvements for the prebuilt recognizers; I specifically provided them with your examples so these issues are better targeted and fully addressed when the new recognizers are released.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Steven :D Is there any specific place where to check for LUIS release's notes? Thanks!

Comment: At the moment, your best option would be to check the [**BF blog**](https://blog.botframework.com/tags?luis) for posts tagged with LUIS. That said, for this week it might pay to keep an eye or ear out for announcements during Microsoft's *[**Build**](http://build.microsoft.com/)*

Comment: Thanks again Steven, will keep an eye at MS Build and BF blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the **builtin.datetimeV2.daterange** prebuilt entity, the *hoy (today)*, *ayer (yesterday)* or *este mes (this month)* are transformed to valid dates.